# 1. Quality standard, 2. Shaded questions

Tags: discussion

I just tried to post the following question, but was rejected because it does not meet the quality standard. What is wrong?

---

Title: Shaded questions

I just noted a new feature introduced. That is, some questions in the list are shaded in blue. What are they?

Tags: discussion

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a minimum length on questions.

At any rate, the answer to your shaded question question [can be found here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange/72593#72593).  Or to summarize:

> We infer a favorite tag based on what questions you visit, if we have a certain statistical confidence that you indeed love this tag. This is based on your history of what questions you've visited.
>
> It's not actually stored in the database, though -- so if you set a favorite tag, it will override this behavior completely.

Basically, they assume since over 50% of the questions you view have that tag, you must be interested in that tag.  I've had it guess at favorite tags for a while, and simply viewing a couple different types of questions makes it go away (or shift to a different tag).

Comment: Thanks. That answers both of my questions perfectly.